# Are there operating systems that aren't based off of or don't use a file/directory system?

Tags: file, operating-system, directory

It seems like there isn't anything inherent in an operating system that would necessarily require that sort of abstraction/metaphor.

If so, what are they? Are they still used anywhere? I'd be especially interested in knowing about examples that can be run/experimented with on a standard desktop computer.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_operating_systems

Comment: Define "OS". A lot of embedded OSes don't have an FS. What's your actual goal? Define "file system", some OSes use (essentially) a DB. What do you want instead?

Comment: Examples of that would be fine. I'm simply interested in exploring alternate OS-level data/app management paradigms. So anything I can get my hands on/explore the structure of would be best.

Comment: This isn't offtopic. This is about organizing things via hierarchy vs other means. For instance, Python's module hierarchies are the same concept as files/directories.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Examples are Persistent Haskell, Squeak Smalltalk, and KeyKOS and its descendants.

> It seems like there isn't anything inherent in an operating system
>   that would necessarily require that sort of abstraction/metaphor.

There isn't any necessity, it's completely bogus. In fact, forcing everything to be accessible via a human readable name is fundamentally flawed, and precludes security due to Zooko's triangle.

Examples of hierarchies similar to this appear as well in DNS, URLs, programming language module systems (Python and Java are two good examples), and torrents, X.509 PKI.

One system that fixes some of the problems caused by DNS/URLs/X.509 PKI is Waterken's [YURL](http://waterken.com/dev/YURL/).

All these systems exhibit ridiculous problems because the system is designed around some fancy hierarchy instead of for something that actually matters.

I've been planning on writing some blogs explaining why these types of systems are bad, I'll update with links to them when I get around to it.

Answer (score 2):

I found this http://pages.stern.nyu.edu/~marriaga/papers/beyond-the-hfs.pdf but it's from 2003. Is something like that what you are looking for?

Answer (score 1):

About 1995, I started to design an object oriented operating system 
(SOOOS) that has no file system.
Almost everything is an object that exists in virtual memory 
which is mapped/paged directly to the disk 
(either local or networked, I.e. redudimentary cloud computing).

There is a lot of overhead in programs to read and write data in specific formats.
Image never reading and writing files.

In SOOOS there are no such things as files and directories,
Autonomous objects, which would essentially replace files, can be organized
suiting your needs, not simply a restrictive hierarchical file system.

There are no low level drive format structures (I.e. clusters)
that have additional level of abstraction and translation overhead.
SOOOS Data storage overhead is simply limited to page tables 
that can be quickly indexed as with basic virtual memory paging.

Autonomous objects each have their own dynamic 
virtual memory space which serves as the persistent data store.
When active they are given a task context and added to the active process task list
and then exist as processes.

A lot of complexity is eliminated in my design, simply instanciate objects
in a program and let the memory manager and virtual memory system handle 
everything consistently with minimal overhead.
Booting the operating system is simply a matter of loading the basic kernal
setting up the virtual memory page tables to the key OS objects and 
(re)starting the OS object tasks.  When the computer is turned-off, 
shutdown is essentially analogous to hibernation
so the OS is nearly in instant-on status,

The parts (pages) of data and code are loaded only as needed.
For example to edit a document, instead of starting a program by loading the entire
executable in memory, simply load the task control structure of the
autonomous object and set the instruction pointer to the function to be performed.
The code is paged in only as the instruction pointer traverses its virtual memory.
Data is always immediately ready to be used and simply paged in only as accessed
with no need to parse files and manage data structures which often
have a distict represention in memory from secondary storage.
Simply use the program's native memory allocation mechanism and
abstract data types without disparate and/or redundent data structures.

Object Linking and Embedding type of program interaction,
memory mapped IO, and interprocess communication you 
get practically for free as one would implement
memory sharing using the facilities of the processor's Memory Management Unit.